# Insert programming code in a Lyx document

Tags: lyx

What is the best way of inserting python/C++ code in a Lyx document? The code is small examples less than 20 lines.

My Lyx document is using the Book document class.

Orjanp

Comment: Here's a related answer for javascript syntax highlighting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420757/syntax-highlighting-javascript-in-lyx-insert-child-program-listing

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There should be an *Insert -> Program Listing* option.  That uses [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) Latex package, so you should have that installed.  The support seems to have been added in [Lyx 1.5](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/NewInLyX15#toc11), and from their screenshot, it seems it gives you a lot of customization options.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: What I did was this.

First I inserted a <box>, then a <program listing>, and in the end a <caption>. By having a box around it I can have a visible frame around the code.

Comment: Is there any way to have syntax highlighting and line numbers?

Comment: To add a caption, place your cursor inside the listing and click on "Insert -> Caption". By default the caption will be shown above the listing. To move the caption to the bottom, open the listing settings dialog ("Edit -> Listing Settings") and switch to the "Advanced" tab. Then add the parameter "captionpos=b".

Comment: One further tip: If you want to change the numbering from "Listing 1.1/1.2/..." to "Listing 1/2/...", add "\lstset{numberbychapter=false}" to your document preamble. See also [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334).

Comment: @Arun Under "Edit -> Listing Settings" you can choose a programming language (Python, C, ...)

Comment: An alternative to @Orjanp's suggested <box> is the built-in option "frame=lines", which you can enter under "Advanced Settings" from within the "Edit -> List Settings" menu item.

Answer (score 74):

I prefer to insert the listings as a child document, so the code is grabbed directly from a file that you can further edit and keep updated (you avoid to duplicate an information and maintenance is a lot easier).
To do this in Lyx:
*Insert->File->Child document*
Then in the window that will appear change the type to program listing and configure it as you need, for example you could want to enter the parameter *language=Python* (you can type a *?* to view all the parameters).
A set of parameters I usually use is:

```
breaklines=true //--> breaks lines to margin
captionpos=b  //--> caption at the bottom of the listing (default is "t")
frame=tb  //--> frame at the top and at the bottom of the listing
language=Python  //--> syntax highlighting for python
```

Comment: is there anyway to get color highlighting? and reduce the indent and font size?

Comment: @waspinator don't know if this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28554/is-there-a-way-to-enable-syntax-highlighting-coloring-in-lyx-for-program-listing

Comment: How can i center it into the middle of the page using lyx ?

Answer (score 6):

The insert->Program Listing feature works great. I just want to add that if you are on Mac, and try to directly paste, using command+V or right-click+paste, a block of code into the program listing, the whitespace will not be preserved, and you have to manually insert the whitespace by typing tabs, returns, etc.

A very easy way to get around this is is to paste using shift+command+V. This preserves all the whitespace of your original source code.

Comment: How can i center it into the middle of the page?
And can change the background color? like grey.